# Должен ли покрывающий индекс включать в себя primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Допустим, есть таблица `A(id int primary key, a varchar(32), b varchar(32), ..., z varchar(32))`.

У меня часто выполняется запрос:
`select count(*) from A where a = :a and b = :b`

Разумным решением видится использование покрывающего индекса на поля `index (a, b)`, чтобы не было лишних обращений к данным.

1. Имеет ли смысл добавлять в него `id`, то есть `index(a, b, id)`?
2. Будет ли он помогать в случаях, если использоваться будут запросы: `select count(*) from A where a = :a` и `select count(*) from A where b = :b`. Или нужно будет создавать отдельные индексы по полям: `index(a)` и `index(b)`?

База данных Postgresql (хотя мне кажется, это не должно влиять).

Comment: 1. Не имеет. 2. Будет помогать только в первом случае. Для второго нужен индекс по полю `b`.

Comment: @Yaant Во втором случае тоже поможет - но гораздо меньше. Просто будет фуллскан компактного индекса, а не пухлой таблицы.

Comment: @Akina А, ну да, просто в формате комментария не стал вдаваться в эти подробности. Равно как и в то, что в зависимости от реализации в конкретной БД индексы `index(a, b)` и `index(a, b, id)` на физическом уровне вполне могут оказаться идентичными. :)

Comment: а покрывающий то зачем, если сами данные не выбираются?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> База данных Postgresql (хотя мне кажется, это не должно влиять).

Это критично важная вещь для любых вопросов производительности.

Индексы в postgresql хранят ссылки на физический адрес строки в датафайлах - `TID`. Поэтому значения первичного ключа не имеют значения и включение полей первичного ключа в индекс без необходимости в этом даже сделают хуже - индекс будет больше занимать места, а значит больше данных будет читаться и писаться на диски, больше памяти занимать в shared_buffers и page cache системы.

> Будет ли он помогать, в случаях, если использоваться будут запросы: select count(*) from A where a = :a и select count(*) from A where b = :b

Зависит от типа индекса. Ответ на первый вопрос - да, возможен быть абстрактным для актуальных версий базы. Ответ на этот второй вопрос придётся рассматривать в отдельности для разных типов индексов.

- `btree` - то, что обычно подразумевают и тип используемый по-умолчанию в `create index`. Это дерево, вы не сможете нормально произвести поиск по дереву, если вы не можете начинать от его корня. Поэтому `btree(a,b)` может ускорить запрос с условием по a, но для условия только по b будет неэффективен - вам придётся просмотреть весь индекс полностью вместо его части.
- `brin` - этому типу индекса не важен порядок участвующих полей. `brin(a,b)` может использоваться и для `a = ?` и для `b = ?`
- `hash` - ну, с этим проще, он просто не умеет многоколоночные индексы.
- `gin`/`gist` немного не о том, и не поддерживают простые типы сами по себе. С расширениями `btree_gin`/`btree_gist` уже возможно построить, но в целом gist и gin это хорошая тема под отдельное сочинение.

---

Немаловажные ещё есть два момента:

- только `btree` может быть сейчас покрывающим индексом
- даже покрывающий `btree` не гарантирует, что таблица читаться не будет. Наоборот, он может гарантировать только то, что, возможно, некоторые блоки этой таблицы читать не придётся.

Такая на первый взгляд странная картина объясняется реализацией механизма MVCC. Индекс  хранит только данные и ссылку на строку, но не хранит данные о транзакционной видимости этой строки. Поэтому каждую строку результата поиска по индексу необходимо проверить, а видна ли эта строка текущей транзакции. Суть `index only scan` в реализации `postgresql` - это возможность пропустить проверку видимости транзакции (и не читать блок данных с таблицы), если для этого блока проставлен бит видимости для всех транзакций в [`visibility map`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-vm.html). Эту битовую карту обновляет `autovacuum` либо ручной `vacuum` и потому это ещё одна причина, почему для хорошей работы postgresql необходимо настраивать autovacuum на более интенсивную работу. Конфиг из коробки - не для работы, а чтобы запуститься где угодно и никому не мешать.

Если visibility map не говорит, что блок виден всем - то базе необходимо прочитать эту часть таблицы и проверить нужные строки. Для активно обновляемых и сильно скоррелированных данных может не быть смысла в покрывающем индексе вовсе.

---

`count` же для MVCC базы вообще жутко неудобная вещь. Для вас это простая циферка, для базы - проверить каждую версию строки в отдельности, видна ли она вам.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

id в Ваших запросах только повредит если его добавить в индекс.
По второму пункту нужно создавать отдельные индексы.